# Running nativescript with angular application on iPhone SE

Tags: nativescript

I am developing mobile app by using nativescript with angular. The issue I am facing is that when I run my app on physical iPhone SE, it becomes over heat and sometimes I didn't see anything on my screen. When I tested with another version iPhone7 and iPhone6, it's ok. If you have some experiences with that please share me.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Zaw Zaw Naing

Comment: I never used iPhone SE, may be it's performance is too low to handle debugging and all. Try installing a release version of your app, it should work smooth like others.

Comment: Maybe there's a lot going on in the background due to unsubscribed Observables. Have a look at https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/ I have no performance / overheating issues whatsoever with an iPhone 5s test device.

Comment: May be @Martin is right, you may verify where exactly it takes too much time by profiling with timeline views.